# Retrieving column and row indices for non-zero values from a list of xts

Tags: r, xts

I have data that looks like:

```
 [[1]]
 KRW.LOW.1
2014-08-08        NA
2014-08-11        -1
2014-08-12        -1
2014-08-13        -1
2014-08-14        -1

[[2]]
MYR.LOW.1
2014-08-08        NA
2014-08-11        -1
2014-08-12        -1
2014-08-13        0
2014-08-14        0
```

These are simply 'signals'. I'm trying to retrieve both the list index and the row index where there are non-zero entries. For instance, from the above example I would want to save [[1]][2],[[1]][3]...[[2]][2], [[2]][3] so that I can use these indices (or signals) to call corresponding values from my raw data.

I don't know what the best way to do this would be. I was thinking of a for() function, but then I realized that this would result in the single bracket indice not matching with the double bracket indice. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
list(structure(c(0, 0, -1, 0, 1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "EUR.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(-1, 0, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "JPY.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "GBP.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "CHF.OPEN")), 
    structure(c(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "AUD.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "CAD.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(-1, 0, -1, 0, 1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "NZD.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SEK.OPEN")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "NOK.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "CZK.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "HUF.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "ILS.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "PLN.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(0, 1, 0, -1, 1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487224800, 1487311200, 1487570400, 
    1487656800, 1487743200), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "RUB.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(-1, -1, 0, -1, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "TRY.HIGH.1")), 
    structure(c(0, 0, 0, -1, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "ZAR.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 0, 0, -1, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "BRL.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "CLP.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "COP.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(1, -1, -1, -1, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "MXN.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, -1, 0, -1, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "PEN.HIGH.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "CNY.CLOSE")), 
    structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "IDR.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487138400, 1487224800, 1487311200, 
    1487570400, 1487743200), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "INR.LOW.1")), 
    structure(c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CST6CDT", class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), index = structure(c(1487311200, 1487570400, 1487656800, 
    1487743200, 1487829600), tzone = "CST6CDT", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "KRW.LOW.1")))
```

Comment: Your code returns multiple `data.frames`, not a `list`. Please use `dput` to show us what your data looks like.

Comment: @ytk Hi, I've already attached dput. When I check str(), it says "List of 25". Also, when I try is.list(x), it returns True. Also, I apologize. It seems it's a list of xts objects, and not a data.frame. I have a bad habit of using the two interchangeably. I'll reattach dput just in case.

Comment: Your `dput` returns multiple `data.frames`, but you say you have a list. Which is it?

Comment: @ytk To my knowledge, it should be a list of data.frames, given that R is returning true for is.list(x) and str(x) says list. I tried using `lapply(x, function(x) dput(tail(x, 5L))` to get the `dput`, which might have messed it up. I apologize. New dput has been edited in.

Answer (score 3):

Let `L` be the input list of xts objects.  Assume that `library(xts)` has been invoked already. The third alternative is the shortest and does not require any packages other than xts which would already be loaded anyways.

**1) melt/lapply** This gives a two-column data frame whose first column is the position within the xts object and whose second column is the index of the list component:

```
library(reshape2)

melt(lapply(L, function(x) which(coredata(x) != 0)))
```

**2) as.data.frame.table/merge** Another possibility is this which gives a 2 column data frame whose first column refers to the positions within the xts object as A, B, C, etc. and whose second column is the column heading of the xts object:

```
s <- subset(as.data.frame.table(coredata(do.call(merge, L) != 0)), Freq)[1:2]
```

The columns are both factors which can optionally be turned to indexes like this:

```
replace(s, TRUE, lapply(s, as.numeric))
```

**3) merge/which w arr.ind** Yet another possibility is:

```
which(do.call(merge, L) != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
```